# I installed an exhaust fan in the attic. I want to power the fan from one or two separate bathrooms

Tags: wiring

Can I see the wiring schematic for option 0 
above

Comment: Which is option 0? Whatever, i would use two relays to make sure the source circuits / supplies don't interfere.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more information before we can help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how better to participate here.

Comment: Do you mean **power** it form **one or two bathrooms** - i.e., actually have the fan in 2 circuits? Or do you simply want to have 3-way switches - 2 switches that either one can turn the fan on or off?

Comment: Do both bathrooms have their own circuits, or do they share a lighting circuit?

Comment: If this is because the bathroom fans exhaust into the attic, fix that ASAP.  Not only will it save you major repairs (or a collapsed roof), it's against code and illegal to rent or sell such a house in many jurisdictions.

Comment: I don’t see a reason for the down vote, not much info in the question, but we can’t help folks by just throwing down votes+. A bit more info would be helpful.